# Storing data in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have trouble storing some data in Firebase. I basically want to store the link and date (from a previous fragment) in my Firebase database.

I can store the link but the date does not seem to be stored in my database on click of the FAB. Any help would be appreciated and the relevant code is below:

```
public class Details extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String KEY_LINK = "link";

RequestQueue requestQueue;

public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 10000;
public static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 15000;

private RecyclerView rv;
private CardView cardView;
FloatingActionButton fab;
private boolean isChecked = true;

private List<Detail> detailList = new ArrayList<>();

private Vibrator vib;

private Firebase firebaseRef;

private static final String FIREBASE_URL = "https://athenajs.firebaseio.com";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

        Intent in = getIntent();

        firebaseRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL).child("favourites");

    //         Get JSON values from previous intent
        final String link = in.getStringExtra(KEY_LINK);
        final String date = in.getStringExtra("date");

        final Favclick mFav = new Favclick(link, date);

        final String pushId = firebaseRef.push().getKey();

        vib = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        cardView = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.cv);
        rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);


        fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setTag(1);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                final int status = (Integer) view.getTag();
                if (status == 1) {
                    fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_white_48dp);
                    Snackbar.make(view, "Added to favourites!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                    view.setTag(0);

                    firebaseRef.child(pushId).setValue(mFav);

                } else {
                    fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_border_white_48dp);
                    Snackbar.make(view, "Removed from favourites!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                    view.setTag(1);
                    firebaseRef.child(pushId).removeValue(null);
                }


            }

        });
```

Comment: Can you share the class definition of `Favclick`?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Firebase favRef = firebaseRef.child("favourites");

Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
data.put("date", date);
data.put("link", link);
favRef.push().setValue(data);
```

In your fab `onClick`method.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering. I managed to work it out using another way. Realised as soon as you answered. Appreciate the help though!